# Not able to download ClickOnce Application

Tags: .net, frameworks, clickonce, web-deployment, connection-timeout

I am facing some serious issues with clickonce. I have been trying to download a clickonce application but everytime I try to download it, the download gets stuck everytime though at different points. I have tried everything from disabling firewall to disabling the anti-virus and also deleting the 2.0 folder but nothing seems to help and also my internet connection is good as I can easily download other large files and the problem is only with clickonce. Here is the error message I am getting:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http//directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/TradeRacer.application
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url     : http://directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/TradeRacer.application
    Application url         : http//directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/Application%20Files/TradeRacer_1_0_0_26/TradeRacer.exe.manifest
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : TradeRacer.application, Version=1.0.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9d50d1580ea5f1ca, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : TradeRacer.exe, Version=1.0.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9d50d1580ea5f1ca, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http//directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/TradeRacer.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http//directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/Application Files/TradeRacer_1_0_0_26/ApplicationData/CHARTBATCHFILE/StockChartX.ocx.deploy did not succeed.
        + The operation has timed out.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [24-May-16 5:00:46 PM] : Activation of http//directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/TradeRacer.application has started.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:48 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:48 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:49 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 2.0.50727.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil using Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil using WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [24-May-16 5:00:51 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [24-May-16 5:07:51 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://directlink.icicidirect.com/TradeRacerLive/Application Files/TradeRacer_1_0_0_26/ApplicationData/CHARTBATCHFILE/StockChartX.ocx.deploy did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The operation has timed out.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Please help me in solving this problem as I really need to download this application.